# SQLAlchemy how to select flat array when I use function instead of nested object with key func_name_1

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have some `category` table, and I'm trying to get flat array something like this

```py
select([psql.array_agg(category.c.name)])
```

Expected result:

```json
["foo", "bar", "etc"]
```

Actual result:

```json
[
  {
    "array_agg_1": ["foo", "bar", "etc"]
  }
]
```

I have tried many different options. But they are all more like workaround. What is most interesting, everything looks good in postgres console.

```sql
select array_agg(name) from category
{foo,bar,etc}
```

Why is this happening and how to solve it without additional subselecting, getting item by key and etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are running `psql` with the `tuples_only` setting enabled, the output of your query is

```
   array_agg   
═══════════════
 {foo,bar,etc}
(1 row)
```

From this we can see that in the absence of an explicit label, Postgresql assigns a label of `array_agg` to the output column.

SQLAlchemy row objects "know" about the column names that they contain, so if you convert them to mappings, for example like this:

```
>>> with engine.connect() as conn:
...     result = conn.execute(sa.select(array_agg(category.c.name)))
...     print(list(result.mappings()))
```

you get

```
[{'array_agg_1': ['foo', 'bar', 'etc']}]
```

But if I convert the result to a list directly, while calling the result's [scalar_one()](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/connections.html?highlight=scalar_one#sqlalchemy.engine.Result.scalar_one) method to indicate that I expect a single row, I get the desired output:

```
>>> with engine.connect() as conn:
...     result = conn.execute(sa.select(array_agg(category.c.name)))
...     print(list(result.scalar_one()))
... 
['foo', 'bar', 'etc']
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation. Is there a similar method for a many objects (list of dicts)?

Comment: I think `result.scalars()` ought to work.